# Setting filter on headers of an Excel sheet via POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi, autofilter

I generate a sheet, pretty bog standard headers and columns of data.

I want to turn on the "Filter" function for the sheet, so the user can easily sort and filter the data.

Can I so this using POI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POI Auto Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114220/poi-auto-filter)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Save the first and last cell from filter area, and execute:

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(firstCell.getRow(), lastCell.getRow(), firstCell.getCol(), lastCell.getCol()));
```

For example, from the below sheet.

```
>x         (x, y)
  0123456  
0|--hhh--|   h = header
1|--+++--|   + = values
2|--+++--|   - = empty fields
3|--+++--|
4|-------|
```

first cell will be the header above the first `+` (2,1) cell. The last will be the last `+` cell (5,3)

Comment: Nice. It seems that I can get away with the following though: s.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:E1")); This range is the header cells only, and does not include the data cells. Still, result is whast I want.

Comment: s.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:N1")); by this we can filter data also.

Comment: did you mean that the last + cell is (4, 3) ?

Comment: I think the API for cell may have changed.  I had to use this range: `new CellRangeAddress( firstCell.getRowIndex(), lastCell.getRowIndex(), firstCell.getColumnIndex(), lastCell.getColumnIndex() )`.  getRow now returns a row instead of an index and getCol no longer exists.

Comment: @Victor by (5,3) do you mean (3,4) ?

Comment: @PrabhatGaur, I wrote this answer 8 years ago. ‍♂️

Comment: The method is now sheet.SetAutoFilter(), with capital S.

Answer (score 29):

easiest way of adding filter on header :

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, numColumns));
sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1);
```

Comment: Small correction: that would be `numColumns - 1` (otherwise you get an extra filter column at the end).

Comment: since numColumns is a var, why would you subtract a value?  since you can just define it , example; if you expect to have 9, you don't need to put it as 10 and subtract 1 ...

Comment: This was more a conceptual remark rather than verbatim code :). The gist is that the constructors for `CellRangeAddress` are zero-indexed and bound-inclusive. So if you are calculating `numColumns` based off of something, you need to take that into consideration.

Comment: I agree with @PriiduNeemre here. I think that `lastIndex` would be more appropiate than `numColumns` (Or I would use `numColumns - 1`)

Answer (score 4):

If you also want to set a filter programmatically, you could use the following:

```
void setAutoFilter(final XSSFSheet sheet, final int column, final String value) {
    sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:Z1"));

    final CTAutoFilter sheetFilter = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter();
    final CTFilterColumn filterColumn = sheetFilter.addNewFilterColumn();
    filterColumn.setColId(column);
    final CTFilter filter = filterColumn.addNewFilters().insertNewFilter(0);
    filter.setVal(value);

    // We have to apply the filter ourselves by hiding the rows: 
    for (final Row row : sheet) {
        for (final Cell c : row) {
            if (c.getColumnIndex() == column && !c.getStringCellValue().equals(value)) {
                final XSSFRow r1 = (XSSFRow) c.getRow();
                if (r1.getRowNum() != 0) { // skip header
                    r1.getCTRow().setHidden(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant Gradle dependencies:

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.9'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.9'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'ooxml-schemas', version: '1.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to do this with NPOI.
You add a CT_AutoFilter to the CT_Table.

I am guessing the it works the same for POI as NPOI.

```
    cttable.autoFilter = new CT_AutoFilter();
    cttable.autoFilter.@ref = "A1:C5";   // value is data and includes header.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the only way that worked for me.  Excel kept blowing away my table using the other answers.

Comment: This effectively does the job: it sets the auto filter in the table (and it goes straight to the table entity). Calling `SetAutoFilter` on the sheet, adds some data to the sheet, but in my case, it also causes excel to complain and repair the document by taking out the table

Answer (score 1):

Use `sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B1:H1"));`

We have to specify only the header cells of the tabular data. Here in my example header starts from cell **B1** and ends at cell **H1**.
Excel will automatically find the data below it and show it in the filter options.